# How can I install Ubuntu and Windows 7 on the same SSD, then use another drive for data storage

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a small SSD (120gb), and a much larger drive (3TB), and want to install both OS's onto the SSD and use the 3TB one for data and gaming storage. Is this possible, and easily doable?
The main thing comes down to getting the bootloader to allow me easy swapping between OS's, and then getting windows to install programs and the like onto the 3TB drive instead of the SSD. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply install Windows on the SSD and then install Ubuntu alongside Windows.   This will give you a dual-boot setup driven by a grub menu.  Both OS's will see your 3TB drive which will be available for data storage in either system.  With a 120 GB SSD, there should be no issues with having sufficient space available for program installation.  I have Windows 7 and Mint 13 running happily together on a 60 GB SSD, with a 1TB disk as supplementary storage.

Comment: Yep, I've done this too. You can then use symlinks to link the spindle drive to somewhere in your home directory. I also linked `/var/tmp`, `/var/log` and `/var/cache` to the spindle drive to reduce SDD writes and prolong its life.